# Tinymce HTMLField Doesn't show in StructBlock

Tags: django, tinymce, wagtail

I'm trying to use HTMLField inside a StructBlock, but the text editor doesn't show...

Any idea if this is the correct way to use the tinymce with blocks.StructBlock ?

Thanks

```swift
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

class BodyBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    content = HTMLField(null=False, blank=True)    # <-- this is the tinymce rich text field
    show_share_buttons = blocks.BooleanBlock(
        verbose_name=_('show share buttons'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_('Whether "Share" buttons will appear at the top left corner of the article body')
    )

    class Meta: # noqa
        template = "blocks/body.html"
        icon = "doc-full"
        label = "Body Ritch Text"
```

#### body.html

```html
<div class="find-page__body main-content">
    {% if self.show_share_buttons %}
        <dv class="not-mobile">
            {% include 'share_buttons.html' with url=page.get_full_url %}
        </dv>
    {% endif %}

    {{ self.content}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a [wagtail plugin](https://github.com/isotoma/wagtailtinymce) for using TinyMCE as a RichText editor. However it was last supported for Wagtail 1.5. You might be able to make it work again - but you will need to load the editor JS into the admin interface and then write the [Telepath adapter](https://wagtail.github.io/telepath/) for it. I really would not recommend investing in that option.

The Hallo text editor, which was deprecated as of Wagtail 2, is finally being removed in Wagtail 3. There is a [separate package](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-hallo) that will let you continue to install it. Does that provide the features you are trying to get by installing TinyMCE? If so, that might be an easier path.

What is it you need that Draftail does not support?

Comment: Can only answer for my case: All of this and then some: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/plugins/ (in other words, lots of power features of modern wysiwyg editors. Draftail is ... lacking.